# ServiceBus Triggers just stop working randomly on Web Jobs, why?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, servicebus

So I've got an Azure Web Job that is using Service Bus Triggers to process info from a Queue. It usually works, and I have it set to process 16 items in parallel. In fact, I even put another copy of the Web Job up so I could handle 32 items at once as my queue gets rather full and it takes awhile to process each item.

So I start the queue load at 11pm, and when I check it around 7am, on occasion the queue will still be half full when it should have been empty. I check the Azure WebJobs Dashboard for both Web Jobs and they have a long list of success messages in the functions invoked section but the most recent one says completed 4 hours ago. My Continuous WebJob Details output window has reached max logging output so reveals nothing. I've even turned on Application Logging (blob storage) so I'm not sure why the console stops pulling in info.

Most nights, it makes it all the way, but some nights it just stops like this. Even with 2 separate web jobs, both end the same way. I've had one night where one stopped, and one kept going, but only processing 1 at a time instead of 16, which it was doing fine earlier that night.  I've got the machine set to always on, the web jobs are continuous. The scale settings are set so between 11pm and 6am it can use more processor, but doesn't create more instances. The web jobs are all sharing a single web site app that is set to Standard Small.

If I reboot the machine or stop and start the Web Jobs, they start going fine again, but the reliability seems so poor and random. I'm not sure if these are 'transient' issues with some hardware changes or glitches or whatnot as I've seen one night. I'm not sure why things just stop, and why it's not just constantly pulling and processing. I feel like I need to just run a while loop instead of a trigger, but from what I understand the trigger is the same thing, only it's supposed to be smarter by not wasting as much cpu with some sort of backoff timers? Do I need to just brute force it and say to hell with wasted cpu? Should I just move to a console app running on a VM?

Hoping for some insight into why this might be happening. I've got a lot of try/catches with email logging of errors if things go wrong and I got this one error from a single call:
"Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. "

Perhaps that's a clue of a transient error and I lost some network or hardware connection and it killed everything, but I only got one error sent to me out of 32 processes running at once.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is your service bus running on Azure?

Comment: In your web app which has webjobs is always on true ?

Comment: @ErkanDemirel It is set to always on.

Comment: I have the same problem.  i'm using webjob sdk and it seems like it just stops pulling messages from the queue randomly sometimes...

Comment: Anybody ever found a solution to this?